# Raising Domain Events For Multiple Subscribers

Tags: c#, domain-events

I am stating to look into the Domain Events pattern and have read a lot of resources on the subject but I cannot find a good way of implementing for our requirements.  Basically we have a Service/Domain layer which wraps the repository layer for reads/writes with a simplistic CQRS implementation.  We have an ASP.NET Mvc application which consumes this service/domain layer.  The whole application is tied together with Autofac and what I would like to happen is for the following:

When a news item is created by calling say "CreateNews" on the service layer register that an event will need to be raised as so:

```
public void CreateNews(Domain.Entities.News.NewsBO news)
{
  ValidateBusinessObject(news);

  var entityNews = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Repositories.Entities.News.News>(news);
  NewsCommandRepository.Create(entityNews);

  _domainEventManager.Register<NewsCreatedDomainEvent>(x => x.News = news);
}
```

This is all happening in a transaction and I don't want to actually raise the event until the save is completed so in our save changes method I want to do this:

```
public void SaveChanges()
{
  _repoCommandManager.SaveChanges();

  _domainEventManager.RaiseEvents();
}
```

Then in our ASP.NET Mvc application I want to have an implementation of an IHandler which looks like this:

```
public class NewsCreatedDomainEventCacheHandler : IHandles<Project.Services.Domain.Events.News.NewsCreatedDomainEvent>
{ 
    public void Handle(Services.Domain.Events.News.NewsCreatedDomainEvent @event)
    {
      // In here we would update the cache or something else particular to the web layer
    }
}
```

I cannot figure out how to go about raising this event from the save method and calling the implementation in the Web.Mvc application.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I have an example of how to do this for you and I happen to be using MVC and AutoFac also!  In my specific example I am concentrating on Command/Query separation but in doing so I had to implement a domain event pattern.

First have a read of this blog post so you get an overview of how things hang together and what the code looks like:
http://www.nootn.com.au/2013/03/command-query-separation-to-better.html

So I would recommend installing the [DotNetAppStarterKit.Web.Mvc NuGet package](http://nuget.org/packages/DotNetAppStarterKit.Web.Mvc/), then take a look at the [Global.asax file](https://github.com/nootn/DotNetAppStarterKit/blob/master/DotNetAppStarterKit.SampleMvc/Global.asax.cs) for how to register all the components you will need.  You can peruse the SampleMvc application for things like [Event Subscribers](https://github.com/nootn/DotNetAppStarterKit/tree/master/DotNetAppStarterKit.SampleMvc/DataProject/EventSubscriber).

I hope this helps and gets you up and going quickly.  You can just use the event publisher/subscriber parts of DotNetAppStarterKit without using commands and queries.